# Responsum of Maimonides Regarding Translating Mishne Torah

Tags: sources-mekorot, rambam, translation, responsa, mishneh-torah

The Maimonides Reader (p. 478) quotes Rambam's responsum to Ibn Gabir regarding translating the MT (also referenced [here](http://dev.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/cgi-bin/itemPrintMode.pl?Id=13090)). He responds to a request from this Arabic speaker who was able to learn Peirush Hamishnayos, but unable to learn MT. Rambam responds that he wont be translating the MT into Arabic, and in fact is translating his Arabic works into Hebrew, but encourages the questioner to pursue his studies.

Does anyone know where else this responsum can be found? (Preferably in the 1859 Kovetz Tshuvos Harambam, the Blau tshuvos, or the P'er Hador tshuvos).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Rambam's responsum to Yoseph ben Gabir you're looking for begins on [the 177th page](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43026&pgnum=177) of *Qovetz Teshuvot ha-Rambam ve-Igrotav* (Leipzig 1859). It's also available [on Sefaria](http://www.sefaria.org/Iggerot_HaRambam.7?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all).

Answer (score 2):

The responsum in question was also translated into English by Leon D. Stitskin and published in *Tradition*. You can access a [PDF from the *Tradition* Archives](http://traditionarchive.org/news/originals/Volume%2017/No.%204/A%20Responsum%20By.pdf) for free.

The relevant excerpt is:

> Keep in mind, however, that I do not intend to produce an Arabic
>   edition of the Mishnah Torah, as it would lose its specific flavor.
>   Moreover, how can you ask me to do this when I hope to translate even
>   my Arabic writings into the holy language.